# Dependency issue Dart

Tags: dependencies, dart, dartium, dart-pub

I am brand new to dart and I am attempting to include "Buckshot: 'any'" into my yaml file.  Unfortuanately I am getting a dependency error when I run pub install.  I am sure that this is a very simple problem but any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Craig

Error:

```
Running pub install ...
Pub install failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Incompatible dependencies on 'logging':
- 'web_ui' depends on it from source 'hosted'
- 'buckshot' depends on it from source 'sdk'
```

Pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name:  TestName
description:  A sample application

dependencies:
   hipster_mvc: 0.2.2
   web_ui: ">=0.2.10 <0.2.11"
   buckshot: 'any'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from incompatible dependencies on the same package. web_ui is looking for *logging* package in [pub](http://pub.dartlang.org) and *buckshot* is looking for *logging* in *dart:sdk*.

Some times ago, [SDK packages have been moved on pub.dartlang.org](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/12/sdk-packages-now-available-on-pub.html).

The [hosted version of buckshot](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/buckshot) looks quite old (0.1.3) and does not handle that modification. However, the last version of the project on github does. So you can use the most recent version of [Buckshot](https://github.com/prujohn/Buckshot) use the following dependencies :

```yaml
dependencies:
  hipster_mvc: 0.2.2
  web_ui: ">=0.2.10 <0.2.11"
  buckshot:
    git: git://github.com/prujohn/Buckshot.git
```